# How do I determine whether a method is visible outside its own assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to identify all members visible outside an assembly. My task right now is with methods. This is what I have so far:

```
bool isVisible = method.IsPublic || method.IsFamily || method.IsFamilyOrAssembly;
```

The problem with this is that explicit interface implementations are not included by this check. How can I identify visible members including explicit interface implementations?

Comment: Did you try google? https://www.google.de/webhp?q=c%23+reflection+find+explicit+interface+implementation

Comment: It is not the only problem, the [InternalsVisibleTo] attribute ought to give you a throbbing headache.  As long as you ask an XY question, the probably correct answer is "don't do it".

Comment: @HansPassant [InternalsVisibleTo] doesn't matter, I only care about members visible from any assembly. Also, I've tried to eliminate XY as much as possible. I actually do need to identify all visible members.

Comment: So you want to know if the class implements a public interface?

Comment: _"explicit interface implementations are not included by this check"_ -- I would argue that technically speaking, such implementations are not in fact "visible" outside the assembly. They may be _used_, but all that is _visible_ per se is the interface type itself. They are no more visible than any other `private` member that is called via some non-private member. In any case, you haven't explained what you've tried in order to address your concern about explicit interface implementations; since these can be identified, why not just look for them and include them in your output?

Comment: @PeterDuniho That's what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to identify a method as being an explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: explicitly implemented interface members are non-public, and include the interface name as part of their name.

Here is a simple code example that retrieves all of the explicitly-implemented members of an interface from a type:

```
private static MemberInfo[] GetExplicitInterfaceMembers(Type type)
{
    HashSet<string> interfaces = new HashSet<string>(
        type.GetInterfaces().Select(i => i.FullName.Replace('+', '.')));
    List<MemberInfo> explicitInterfaceMembers = new List<MemberInfo>();

    foreach (MemberInfo member in type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        int lastDot = member.Name.LastIndexOf('.');

        if (lastDot < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        string interfaceType = member.Name.Substring(0, lastDot);

        if (interfaces.Contains(interfaceType))
        {
            explicitInterfaceMembers.Add(member);
        }
    }

    return explicitInterfaceMembers.ToArray();
}
```

(Note that while nested types are given a name with `+` in it for the level of nesting, the type name as included in the member name of explicitly implemented interfaces has the usual `.`)

I assume that given the above example, you can modify the basic logic to suit your specific need.

I make no promises that the above will comprehensively identify all explicitly implemented interface members in a class for all possible interface types, but I *think* it will and in any case, I'm pretty sure the above will work for "normal" code (i.e. the only way I can think of for an exception to occur would be for some kind of odd, programmatically-generated code scenario, with which I am less familiar).